# App Metric for current user installs for IOS apps.

Tags: ios, metric

I'm searching for an App metric for 'current user installs' for IOS apps. The google play store already provide this metric for Android apps. Does anybody know if this metric is also available for iOS apps?

Comment: Yes, You can find the app metric details available in your itunesconnect account under the heading **App Analytics**

Answer (score 2):

Login to [iTunesConnect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/)

Under App Analytics, you can find active devices on the metric section.

[image]

It is important to remember, this active devices are opt in only. Only the users who have enabled apple to collect data, only those users data will be shown here.